# How to automatically persist all Spring StateMachine transactions, actions and so on?

Tags: spring-boot, saga, spring-statemachine

I am using spring statemachine and actually I'm able to persist the `state_machine` because I'm using the `StateMachineRuntimePersister`. The problem is when i look to for example the table `transition` nothing is there, it seems that it was not persisted.

My configuration below:

```
@Configuration
public class StateMachineJPAPersistence {

    @Bean
    public StateMachineRuntimePersister<DomainState, DomainEvent, String> stateMachineRuntimePersister(JpaStateMachineRepository jpaStateMachineRepository) {
        return new JpaPersistingStateMachineInterceptor<>(jpaStateMachineRepository);
    }


    @Bean
    public StateMachineService<DomainState, DomainEvent> stateMachineService(StateMachineFactory<DomainState, DomainEvent> stateMachineFactory, StateMachineRuntimePersister<DomainState, DomainEvent, String> stateMachinePersist) {
        return new DefaultStateMachineService<>(stateMachineFactory, stateMachinePersist);
    }

}
```

And i use it on my StateMachineConfig

```
    config.withConfiguration()
            .autoStartup(Boolean.FALSE)
            .listener(stateMachineListener)
            .and()
            .withPersistence()
            .runtimePersister(stateMachineRuntimePersister);
```

I want all these spring state-machine metadata to be persisted (guard, transitions, actions and so on). Does Spring StateMachine have this functionality out of the box?